# How to let the user draw an ellipse?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm making a simple paint program with javascript. The circle-tool is working as intended, but how do I add a tool for drawing an ellipse/oval?

I have reused much of the code for making the different tools (pencil, line, rectangle, and circle), and so far so good. But I can't get the code for drawing the ellipse right.

Here's the current and working code for drawing a circle filled with a random color:

```
var radius = Math.max(
Math.abs(ev._x - tool.x0),
Math.abs(ev._y - tool.y0)
) / 2;

var x = Math.min(ev._x, tool.x0) + radius;
var y = Math.min(ev._y, tool.y0) + radius;

context.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + 360 * Math.random() + ', 85%, 50%)';
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
context.fill();
```

I've tried to integrate it with the code already in use and the context.scale, but I don't get it right:

```
var radius = Math.max(
Math.abs(ev._x - tool.x0),
Math.abs(ev._y - tool.y0)
) / 2;

var radius2 = ;

var x = Math.min(ev._x, tool.x0) + radius;
var y = Math.min(ev._y, tool.y0) + radius;

context.save();
context.scale(1,  radius2/radius);
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.restore();
context.lineWidth=2;
context.strokeStyle="#000";
context.stroke();
```

Is the var radius correct, and do I write the var radius2? The entire code is here [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/liqihix/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

1. The x attribute defines the x coordinate of the center of the ellipse
2. The y attribute defines the y coordinate of the center of the ellipse
3. The radiusX attribute defines the horizontal radius
4. The ry attribute defines the vertical radius

Image for your reference[image]

Comment: Thank you! The biggest problem is really how to implement this into the code I've already got.